# Correios API request

Tags: c#, api

Possuo um problema com meu código c#,estou tentando consumir a api dos correios porém os dados vem nulo, eu encontrei um outro tutorial na internet que dizia para instanciar a classe rastro e pegar a propriedade rastroJSON mas meu serviço não possui essa propriedade(rastroJSON), sendo essa propriedade rastroJSON exibida na página 7 da documentação dos correios.
Minha tentativa vindo os dados nulos:

```
            correios.rastro a = new correios.rastro();
            correios.sroxml xml = new correios.sroxml();
            xml = a.buscaEventos("ECT", "SRO", "", "U", "", "CODIGO");
            Console.WriteLine(xml.objeto);
            Console.ReadKey();
```

correios é o namespace da minha referencia.

o objeto do consolewriteline vem nulo, eu criei uma referencia de serviço com o endereço:
http://webservice.correios.com.br/service/rastro/Rastro.wsdl

tentei seguir o manual:
https://www.correios.com.br/para-voce/correios-de-a-a-z/pdf/rastreamento-de-objetos/manual_rastreamentoobjetosws.pdf, mas não funcionou.

Eu criei primeiro com uma referencia de serviço, logo em seguida tentei criando uma referencia de serviço web, nas propriedades avançadas.

Comment: O Usuário , Senha imagino que você tenha, correto? Teste com a chamada abaixo colocando os dados na URL:
Como eu não tenho usuario e senha aqui pra testar pra mim retorna null também.

http://webservice.correios.com.br/service/rastro/Rastro.wsdl?%22usuario=9999999999&senha=S@1234YWC5&tipo=L&resultado=T&lingua=101&objetos=JO999999999BR

Comment: Estou com este problema também, vc conseguiu dar um jeito?

Answer (score 1):

O seu código está correto.

```
    correios.rastro a = new correios.rastro();
    correios.sroxml xml = new correios.sroxml();
    xml = a.buscaEventos("usuario", "senha", "tipo", "resultado", "lingua", "objetos");
    Console.WriteLine(xml.objeto);
    Console.ReadKey();
```

Para o buscaEventos você tem esses parâmetros:

**usuario**

Informado pela área
comercial dos Correios na
ativação do serviço. Este
campo diferencia letras
maiúsculas e minúsculas
(case-sensitive).

**senha**

Informado pela área
comercial dos Correios na 
ativação do serviço. Este
campo diferencia letras
maiúsculas e min

**tipo**

L: lista de objetos. O
servidor fará a consulta
individual de cada
identificador informado; F:
intervalo de objetos. O
servidor fará a consulta
sequencial do primeiro ao
último objeto informado,

**resultado**

T: serão retornados todos
os eventos do objeto; U:
será retornado apenas o
último evento do objeto.

**lingua**

101: Serão retornados
todos os eventos no
idioma Português
102: Serão retornados
todos os eventos no
idioma Inglês.

**objetos**

Código do objeto formado
por 2 letras, 9 números e 2
letras. Este campo
diferencia letras maiúsculas
e minúsculas (casesensitive).
Exemplo: AA458226057BR
(sempre informar tudo em
letras maiúsculas).

Exemplo:
[http://webservice.correios.com.br/service/rastro/Rastro.wsdl?"usuario=9999999999&senha=S@1234YWC5&tipo=L&resultado=T&lingua=101&objetos=JO999999999BR](http://webservice.correios.com.br/service/rastro/Rastro.wsdl?%22usuario=9999999999&senha=S@1234YWC5&tipo=%20L&resultado=T&lingua=101&objetos=JO999999999BR)

Answer (score 0):

Consegui identificar o problema. Ao importar a referência do WSDL a classe sroxml com propriedades explícitas, uma delas é a que está retornando null **objeto**.

```
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("objeto", Order=4)]
        public objeto[] objeto {
            get {
                return this.objetoField;
            }
            set {
                this.objetoField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("objeto");
            }
        }
```

Basta alterar o valor do primeiro parâmetro do XmlElementAttribute para **Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified**:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=4)]
```

Tente executar a chamada do WebService novamente e vc terá a response tipada.

Não sei porque o wsdl está configurado para gerar a classe dessa maneira, só sei que apenas alterando isso o WebService passou a trazer o objeto completo.

Existem outros campos com esse mesmo problema, basta repetir a solução.